# Is there a way to pull the complete download path of the python libtorrent module?

Tags: python, save, torrent, libtorrent

I have tried using

```
myvar = handle.save_path
```

But when I try to call the variable, I get `<bound method save_path of <libtorrent.torrent_handle object at 0x7f906d3e38d0>>`
How do I call the full save path of the torrent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean "get" when you say "pull" and "call" (i.e. you have a `torrent_handle` and you want to know what its save path is); you can ask for the `torrent_status` by calling `handle.status()` and the torrent status object has a `save_path` member.

It's documented [here](https://libtorrent.org/reference-Torrent_Handle.html#status) and [here](https://libtorrent.org/reference-Torrent_Status.html#torrent_status).